# Datepicker maxDate limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following code and I want to use `maxDate` only if `selector === '#Birth'`.
How can I achieve that?

```
function customdatepicker(selector) {
    $(selector).datepicker({
        inline: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        prevText: '<',
        nextText: '>',
        maxDate: 0
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`option`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option) (`datepicker('option', ...)`) method for updating the maximum date of your picker after its initialization.

```js
customdatepicker('#test');
customdatepicker('#Birth');

function customdatepicker(selector) {
  const picker = $(selector).datepicker({
    inline: true,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    prevText: '<',
    nextText: '>'
  });
  
  if (selector === '#Birth') {
    // Impossible to choose a date after the 20th of May 2019.
    picker.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', '20/05/2019');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<label for="test">Date: <input type="text" id="test"></label>
<label for="Birth">Birth: <input type="text" id="Birth"></label>
```